# why destructuring object keys gives an error in javascript?

Tags: javascript

for example, I have an object
but when i send this object key inside curly brackets it gives error.

```js
const user = {name: "fishLegs"}
userModerl.create({user.name})
```

while taking that key inside another variable makes it work fine.
Why so?

```js
const user = {name: "fishLegs"}
let userName = user.name
userModerl.create({userName})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, objects are key-value pairs.

Normally, if you try to list a plain expression (a value) inside an object literal, the syntax will not be valid, because you need both a value and a key. That's why `{user.name}` fails.

There's an exception, though: if you have a *standalone variable* (not something that's a property of an object, it needs to be a standalone identifer), listing just that identifier creates a property on the object *with the same name as the variable*, with a value of what's contained in the variable.

```
{ someVar }
```

is equivalent to

```
{ someVar: someVar }
```

but such a thing can't be done (and doesn't really make sense) for

```
{ user.name }
```

Comment: There’s a [proposal](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-shorthand-improvements#object-initializers) to make this syntax possible.

Comment: so i can write userModel.create({name : user.name}).. makes sense now

Comment: i thought it would automatically take that key of the first object and make its own key with same name